# How to send data from one android phone to another with or without server?

Tags: android, gps, location

I need help with my android app, what I basically want to do is send "location" of
one phone to another (not via sms) and put that location on google maps of the receiver so that he can navigate to that place.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a socket server to push the data from one user to the other.

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

As a related note, the popular google application Lattitude does exactly this: Shares you location with a friend on a google map. So another approach would be to use Lattitude as an intent.